# How to update or refresh the Remove Object at index in IOS? For this scenario

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I created two buttons add row(UI) and delete row(programatically).If i press add row button programatically created text boxes and delete button gets iterate.While pressing delete button it deletes the entire row.Please take a look at below Images.

[image]

first Image is about the default showing of programatically created text boxes,add row(created via UI) and delete buttons.

[image]

second Image is about the add row button.If i pressed add row button text box and delete button gets iterated.

[image]

Third Image is about values entering into text box manually.

[image]

Fourth Image is about.I entered value 1 in the first text box and press delete button.then entire row gets deleted.

[image]

Fifth Image is about after I press add row button from the fourth link or screen shot,the first text box should be empty(what I am expecting) .But it fills with the value 1.

My piece of code for creating delete button and text boxes inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// table view created via storyboard.
if (tableView == self.tblview)
{
// create a delete button dynamically     
UIButton *delete = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
delete.frame = CGRectMake(525.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
[delete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:delete];
[delete addTarget:selfaction:@selector(deleterow:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[delete setTag:indexPath.row];

//dynamically created text fields.
UITextField *txtvalue =  [[UITextField alloc] init];
}
}
```

Method or Action delete row: this action performs the deletion of entire row by removeObjectAtIndex and del row defines which row.

```
- (IBAction)deleterow:(id)sender
{
UIButton * delete = (UIButton *) sender;
// del row defines the which row of the delete tag has been pressed.
NSInteger delRow = delete.tag;
[self.Array removeObjectAtIndex:delRow];
[self.tblview reloadData];
}
```

Action Add row:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender 
{
[self Data:[self.Array count]];
[self.tblview reloadData];
}
```

Where Array is the mutable array.I found out no issue with the add row  button. Then i tried something using retain syntax inside delete row action.But it doesn't works.How to rectify this issue.Please,Thanks in Advance.

The Delete row action performs the following things:

when I put the logger before the self.array it shows the values like this:

```
(
{
"2016-01-31" = 1;
"2016-02-01" = "";
"2016-02-02" = "";
"2016-02-03" = "";
"2016-02-04" = "";
"2016-02-05" = "";
"2016-02-06" = "";
A = x;
b = x;
C = "";
D = "";
E = "";
F = "";
G = “RED";
H = 8;
}
)
```

After that delete operation takes place.Before that,Is it possible to change the "2016-01-31" = 1; to  "2016-01-31" = "";In the mutable array.It's the right solution or else any other options?

Comment: help me on this...please

Comment: Please anybody give hint regarding this.

Comment: Where are you creating/reusing the cell and returning it in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Please add the relevant code as well.

Comment: @ZeMoon  relevant code means ...I think delete button might be the problem.Is there any other possibility for not getting desired result.You are asking full code of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes. This is because you seem to be adding multiple delete buttons. It would be best to reuse the button or remove them before adding new ones. One cannot determine that using the code you have posted currently.

Comment: Also, the text `If i press add row button programatically created text boxes and delete button gets iterate.While pressing delete button it deletes the entire row` is difficult to understand. Please explain what your are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: 1.http://i.imgur.com/ezHapau.png  when i load my application screen shot should be like this. then i click the add row button all the dropdowns,text boxes,has been iterated or increased 2.http://i.imgur.com/1g1KDKe.png then entering values like this 3.http://i.imgur.com/B3ilAvO.png  after that i deleted the second row,then 4.http://i.imgur.com/RNvxpjc.png my screen shot like this.Then, again i pressing add row the text boxes should be empty mentioned in second screen shot.But it fills with values.like this 5.http://i.imgur.com/FEL2ObC.png

Comment: @ZeMoon i think the issue should be in the delete row action.So now you can understand this

Comment: @ZeMoon are u der bro...

Comment: could you give your mail id bro...i will send my demo project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells in table views are reused. With this in mind, in Cocoa's [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) pattern, you should make sure that these cells (the "view" of Model-View-Controller) have some place to store the values as the user types them (the "model") and the view controller (the "controller") will facilitate the updating of the model as you add, delete and update rows, as well as making sure that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` sets the contents of those seven text fields based upon the values in your model.

But your code snippets doesn't contemplate any model (or, if this `self.Array` is supposed to be the model, you don't appear to do anything to (a) save the values as the user types them; nor (b) load the cell with the the values from the model when you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). As a result, when a cell is reused, whatever values that were in those text fields last may appear in those cells.

---

By way of example, let's imagine that I have cell prototype linked to a cell subclass that has the seven outlets for the seven labels:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField7;

@end

@implementation CustomCell

// this is intentionally blank

@end
```

And then my view controller (a) populates model structure as you add rows; (b) updates model as rows are updated; and (c) removes entry from model when rows are deleted. Note, I didn't know what your model object was, but as it seemed to have seven small text fields, I assumed it might be a "phone number". If not, rename that model object to whatever is appropriate for your case.

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

/// Phone number model object

@interface PhoneNumber : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit4;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit5;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit6;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *digit7;
@end

@implementation PhoneNumber

// this is intentionally blank

@end


@interface ViewController ()

/// An array of model objects

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<PhoneNumber *> *phoneNumbers;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize that array
    self.phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
}

// return the number of items in our array of model objects

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.phoneNumbers.count;
}

// when I populate cell, make sure to populate the seven text fields on the basis of the corresponding model object

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PhoneNumber *number = self.phoneNumbers[indexPath.row];

    cell.textField1.text = number.digit1;
    cell.textField2.text = number.digit2;
    cell.textField3.text = number.digit3;
    cell.textField4.text = number.digit4;
    cell.textField5.text = number.digit5;
    cell.textField6.text = number.digit6;
    cell.textField7.text = number.digit7;

    return cell;
}

// I hooked up "editing change" action in the seven text fields to this method in the view controller
// which updates the model

- (IBAction)didEditingChangeTextField:(UITextField *)sender {
    CustomCell *cell = (id)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]], @"%@ is not CustomCell", sender);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSAssert(indexPath, @"did not find indexPath");

    PhoneNumber *phoneNumber = self.phoneNumbers[indexPath.row];

    if (sender == cell.textField1)
        phoneNumber.digit1 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField2)
        phoneNumber.digit2 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField3)
        phoneNumber.digit3 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField4)
        phoneNumber.digit4 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField5)
        phoneNumber.digit5 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField6)
        phoneNumber.digit6 = sender.text;
    else if (sender == cell.textField7)
        phoneNumber.digit7 = sender.text;
}

// when I delete row, just delete from model object from array and then tell tableview to remove that row

- (IBAction)didTapDeleteButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    CustomCell *cell = (id)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]], @"%@ is not CustomCell", sender);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSAssert(indexPath, @"did not find indexPath");

    [self.phoneNumbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}

// when I add row, just add to model collection and then tell table view to add that row

- (IBAction)didTapAddButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.phoneNumbers.count inSection:0];
    [self.phoneNumbers addObject:[[PhoneNumber alloc] init]];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}

@end
```

Comment: If i save the entered values, then updation it provides the desired result.

Comment: I've added code sample of how you'd generally do this in MVC model.

Comment: thanks a lot sir... i will try and let you know sir.

Comment: Is it possible to use the prepareforreuse method for this?

Comment: @djonthe - You can, but you still need to set the values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And as, [the `prepareForReuse` documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) "For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should always reset all content when reusing a cell."

Comment: sir please take a look at this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433207/values-passing-from-one-controller-to-another-works-fine-in-iphone-but-not-in-ip