# Values passing from one controller to another works fine in iPhone but not in iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uibutton

In my app,Passing values from one controller to another,works fine in iPhone destination but not in iPad.

1.This image shows the date picker in iPhone

[image]

2.This image shows the value selected into text box.

[image]

3.After clicks the "continue" button.It passes the values to next controller.

[image]

This works fine in "iPhone" destination.

4.This image shows date picker in iPad.

[image]

5.This image shows the value selected into text box.

[image]

6.After, clicks the "continue" button.value is not gets displayed in next controller in iPad.

[image]

My Piece of code for passing values from one controller to another:

```
On view controller1.m file 

#import "ViewController1.h"
#import “ViewController2.h”
//datepicker date value set to the text box.
[self.txtStartDate setInputView:dpStartDate];

//Function to pass the value from one controller to another
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
ViewController2 * destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
//self.startday is the string 
destViewController.startday= self.txtStartDate.text;
}

//button action to move to next controller
- (IBAction)btnContinue:(id)sender 
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@“ViewController2" sender:self];
}
```

Then in viewcontroller2.m file

```
#import “ViewController2.h"
_datelabel.text = self.startday;
NSLog(@“%@“,self.startday);
```

In Iphone destination on logger it shows:

2016-02-14

In ipad destination on logger it shows:

null.

I connect the two controllers,via storyboard through the triggered segue show.

But  I had done this task,previously by connecting "continue" button action directly with other controller(show).It works fine only.

what might be the issue?How to rectify it.It can be resolved through story board or any code changes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me on this.

Comment: please any one help me what might be the issue